# Send an HTTP request to a URL using PHP

Tags: php, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I am trying to send an HTTP request to an URL using the below code,but keep getting error

> (file_get_contents(http://localhost:81/Help/Api/POST-SMS): failed to
>   open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error)

, any idea?
Thank in advance

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost:81/Help/Api/POST-SMS';
 $data = array('message' => 'hi', 'mobile' => '12345678');
$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
)
);
 $context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: yea, it said failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

From the server response "HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" - that means the http://localhost:81/Help/Api/POST-SMS failed - not your actual script that you posted above.

I also recommend using the curl approach in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Another exemple that might help you is this: [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I'd try to look into it'